# Настройка selenium WebDrivee через переменные окружения

Tags: java, selenium

коллеги
Мне нужно с selenium протестировать и нужно установить проперти в webdriver именно так -
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER"));
У меня винда, создал переменную окружения, естественно скачал driver и при запуске падает с ошибкой -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\IdeaProjects\FirstHomework\ C:\chrome\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe
Как-будто добавляет к пути к драйверу путь к проекту, хотя если запихнуть System.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER") в стрингу , то в дебаге нормальный путь из переменной.
А вот так - нормально работает - System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\chrome\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"); Где я допускаю ошибку и как правильно настроить?
Вот мой метод инициализации -

```
@BeforeEach
public void inti() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER"));
    chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что в переменных окружения нужно было использовать двойной слеш, так как java воспринимает одинарный слеш как символ для экранирования